# find xpath for colour

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Find the XPath with respect to background colour

```
<div style="margin-right: 8px; position: relative; width: 8px; height: 8px; border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block; background-color: #f04d3b;"></div>
```

I want xpath for background-color

```
//div[@class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align"]/div[contains(@style(),'#f04d3b')]
//div[@class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align"]/div[contains(@background-color(),'#f04d3b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` is not an attribute, it's a property in style attribute. So you have to change the xpath as shown below.

```
//div[@class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align"]/div[contains(@style(),'#f04d3b')] //div[@class="jqx-grid-cell-left-align"]//div[contains(@style,'background-color: #f04d3b')]
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolve, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button on the left hand side.